# Look if loopback model property array contains a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I have a Loopback moddel that looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "string",
 "elements": [
      "string"
  ]
}
```

Now I want to filter if `elements` property conatins a certain string.
Something like this:

```
User.find({
     filter: {
         where: {elements: $scope.objects[i].id} //doesn't work, I want sth like "element contains $scope.objects[i].id
     }}, function (user) {
        console.log(user);
});
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Warning:** This solution was meant to answer the question "how do I filter a list of objects". It was accepted so I can't remove it. I don't know anything about LoopBack which has performance implications I'm not privy to. So please keep searching if you are looking for a "LoopBack" best practice.

---

This seems like a javascript question to me. The elements property contains an array so you can filter that array with filter().

```
yourModel = {      // <-- Using a plain object for demo.
 "name": "string",
 "elements": [
      "string"
  ]
}

matchingElements = yourModel.elements.filter(function(elm){ return elm === $scope.objects[i].id});

didMyModelHaveTheElement = matchingElments.length > 0;
```

Comment: Please provide a reason if you down vote.  I did see there was a typo which I fixed, was that the reason?

Comment: consider that the DB contains a million records of users.
And, there are limited users who have `element - "string"`, such 'things' shouldn't be filtered on the server side by pulling those million records. hence, that one downvote and mine too...for making me write this.

Comment: Ah, thought he just meant custom js objects.  didn't realize "LoopBack" was a thing. Like hibernate orm objects.  I'll remove my answer.